# Can the notches in the scope be used to calculate bullet drop?

Tags: sniper-elite-3

Sniper Elite 3 has (purportedly) realistic bullet drop programmed into it. Knowing this, I was curious if there was a way to utilize the notches in the scope when calculating bullet drop.

[image: Scope]

Comment: It sounds like they're trying to do that in the game. Tried a few shots to see how well it works? Probably have to guess the distance though

Comment: @Xen2050 The game has a firing range with clearly marked distances, so I can try out test shots in a controlled environment. There's clearly consistent drop but I can't find an obvious correlation with the scope marks and I don't have enough knowledge of firearms to say that the marks are or aren't working as intended.

Comment: I haven't played that long, but as far as I figured out each longer line represents ~50 meter. But that needs more verification :D